# Prefetch related after many-to-one relation

Tags: django, django-admin, django-queryset

I have the following (simplified) model structure:

```
class Article(Model):
    @property
    def article_number(self) -> str:
        return self.attributes.get(masterdata_type__code='article_number').value

class Attribute(Model):
    article = ForeignKey(Article, null=True, blank=True, related_name='attributes')
    masterdata_type = ForeignKey(Type, related_name='attributes')
    value = CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, db_index=True)

class Type(Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

In the admin panel, I want to show a list of 100s of articles and show its article_number. This now result in 100s of database calls (which I can see using Silk monitoring), so I want to prefetch those objects. I tried the following solutions in the admin panel, but all didn't work. What is the proper way to reduce number of database calls here?

I am using Django 1.8.14, with a PostgreSQL backend.

**Solutions that don't work:**

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    queryset = super(ArticleSetAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    return queryset.prefetch_related('attributes__masterdata_type')
```

Still 100s of database calls.

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    queryset = super(ArticleSetAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    return queryset.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('attributes', queryset=Attribute.objects.select_related('masterdata_type')))
```

Still 100s of database calls.

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    queryset = super(ArticleSetAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    return queryset.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('attributes', queryset=Attribute.objects.prefetch_related('masterdata_type')))
```

Still 100s of database calls.

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    queryset = super(ArticleSetAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    return queryset.select_related('attributes__masterdata_type')
```

Error, since attributes is Many-to-One relationship to Article.

Comment: Post the full article model please

Comment: You need to show more of your code as its not get_queryset that is causing the problem. Are you looking up related objects in the view or the template? Are you filtering on something when you are getting the related objects - these can trigger extra database calls.

Comment: the best solution would be to install django-debug-toolbar, and see what the extra queries are and which line of code is triggering them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter the queryset in the `Prefetch` object, otherwise the `get()` in the `article_number` causes a new query.

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    queryset = super(ArticleSetAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    return queryset.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            'attributes',
            queryset=Attribute.objects.filter(masterdata_type__code='article_number'),
            to_attr=article_number_attributes,
        )
    )
```

I've used the `to_attr` argument so that we don't overwrite `attributes` with the filtered queryset. You then need to update your `article_number` to use the new attribute.

```
@property
def article_number(self):
    return self.article_number_attributes[0].value
```

Comment: I see, I will try it! How should I change this example if I want to have two attributes (let's say article_number and article_category) displayed in the admin panel? I can use the filter with `masterdata_type__code__in=['article_number', 'article_category']`, but how would I reference the correct attribute in the correct getter method on model `Article`? Could I store multiple attributes as a dictionary?

Comment: One option is to use two `Prefetch` objects with two different querysets, e.g. `queryset.prefetch_related(Prefetch(...), Prefetch(...))`. If you use `masterdata_type__code__in=['article_number', 'article_category']` in the Prefetch's queryeset, then you would have to loop through the list in your getter and use the correct item (you might have to add `select_related` to the Prefetch's queryset to prevent multiple queries). The `Prefetch` api doesn't let you customise the format of the data. If you want a dictionary, you'll have to create it.